# titlesec smallcaps not working with the Lato font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, titlesec, section-titles

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

The word 'Introduction' is not in small-caps. How can I fix this?
One way I can think of is to use a different font-family for the section titles, but I don't know how to configure that with `titlesec`.

Comment: recent versions of the lato font do not provide small caps support, even 'fake' ones http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/lato/doc/lato.pdf

Comment: @Yorgos "Anyway LATEX should automatically substitute missing smallcap shapes by normal ones." this doesn't happen though

Comment: yes that happens. Instead of small caps latex uses the regular shape of lato.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh alright, I misinterpreted it. Is there a way to use a different font only for the title?

Comment: sure, you can use any font, check the titlesec documentation.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution that works on `pdfLatex`:
Add `\usepackage{newtxtext}` before your main font

Comment: newtxtext is a serif font, whereas lato is a sans-serfif one... thus, i don;t see your answer very useful. The OP wants a different font for his/her section title. Not the entire document

Comment: @Yorgos I am the OP

Comment: Yes I saw it, but your answer does not solve the problem you actually asking (how to implement small caps only for the section title using the lato font)